# Uncaught exception error! Simple document app

Tags: iphone, ios, uncaught-exception

Removed the colon which wasn't supposed to be there since my selector doesn't have one.  It fixed it, then this problem occurred:

```
    2012-06-02 22:33:10.083 TinyPix[10433:fb03] load OK
2012-06-02 22:33:10.084 TinyPix[10433:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<BIDTinyPixDocument 0x6e665a0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key timeStamp.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x16b0022 0x1841cd6 0x16afee1 0x9c8efe 0x937831 0x936c99 0x5f47 0x5e77 0x93af30 0x93aedb 0x59ed 0x4546e3 0x40778d9 0x4078509 0x15e7803 0x15e6d84 0x15e6c9b 0x15997d8 0x159988a 0x1b626 0x2a5d 0x29c5)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Here's my detail file: I'm getting a SIGABRT error on the self.detailDescriptionLabel.text line. Don't know what's going on.

```
#import "BIDDetailViewController.h"

@interface BIDDetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation BIDDetailViewController

@synthesize detailItem = _detailItem;
@synthesize detailDescriptionLabel = _detailDescriptionLabel;

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    self.detailDescriptionLabel = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Here's my file:

```
#import "BIDMasterViewController.h"
#import "BIDTinyPixDocument.h"

#import "BIDDetailViewController.h"

@interface BIDMasterViewController () <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *documentFilenames;
@property (strong, nonatomic) BIDTinyPixDocument *chosenDocument;
-(NSURL *)urlForFilename:(NSString *)filename;
-(void)reloadFiles;
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@implementation BIDMasterViewController
@synthesize colorControl;
@synthesize documentFilenames;
@synthesize chosenDocument;

@synthesize fetchedResultsController = __fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger selectedColorIndex = [prefs integerForKey:@"selectedColorIndex"];
    self.colorControl.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedColorIndex;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    [self reloadFiles];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)insertNewObject
{
// get the name
    UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filename"
                               message:@"Enter a name for your new TinyPix document."
                              delegate:self
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                     otherButtonTitles:@"Create", nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];
}

#pragma mark - Table View



- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }   
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // The table view should not be re-orderable.
    return NO;
}



#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}    

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

/*
// Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed. 

 - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
 */

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];
}

-(NSURL *)urlForFilename:(NSString *)filename {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    return url;
}

-(void)reloadFiles {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSError *dirError;
    NSArray *files = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&dirError];
    if (!files) {
        NSLog(@"Encountered error while trying to list files in directory %@: %@", path, dirError);
    }

    NSLog(@"found files: %@", files);

    files = [files sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id filename1, id filename2) {
        NSDictionary *attr1 = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename1]
                                                   error:nil];
        NSDictionary *attr2 = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename2]
                                                                                        error:nil];
                               return [[attr2 objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate] compare:[attr1 objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate]];
                               }];

        self.documentFilenames = files;
        [self.tableView reloadData];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.documentFilenames count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FileCell"];

    NSString *path = [self.documentFilenames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = path.lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension;
    return cell;
}


-(IBAction)chooseColor:(id)sender {
    NSInteger selectedColorIndex = [(UISegmentedControl *)sender selectedSegmentIndex];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:selectedColorIndex forKey:@"selectedColorIndex"];
}


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.tinypix",
                              [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text];
        NSURL *saveUrl = [self urlForFilename:filename];
        self.chosenDocument = [[BIDTinyPixDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:saveUrl];
        [chosenDocument saveToURL:saveUrl
                 forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
                completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                    if (success) {
                        NSLog(@"save OK");
                        [self reloadFiles];
                        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"masterToDetail"
                                                  sender:self];
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"failed to save!");
                    }
                }];
    }
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if (sender == self) {
        // if sender == self, a new document has just been created,
        // and chosenDocument is already set.

        UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
        if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setDetailItem:)]) {
            [destination setValue:self.chosenDocument forKey:@"detailItem"];
        }
    }else {
        // find the chose document from the tableview
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *filename = [documentFilenames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSURL *docUrl = [self urlForFilename:filename];
        self.chosenDocument = [[BIDTinyPixDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:docUrl];
        [self.chosenDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
                NSLog(@"load OK");
                UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
                if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setDetailItem:)]) {
                    [destination setValue:self.chosenDocument forKey:@"detailItem"];
                }
            }else {
                NSLog(@"failed to load!");
            }
        }];
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the selector as `insertNewObject:` and the colon on the end says that it takes one parameter.  The `insertNewObject` method you implemented takes no parameters and, to Objective-C, that makes it a different thing and it can't find the one parameter method.

You should change your implementation to `- (IBAction)insertNewObject:(id)sender {...}` to match `@selector(insertNewObject:)`.

Comment: Nevermind everybody, I downloaded the exact project from the book source code and it still wouldn't work.  what a joke.  Thanks for the time though